# Prove convergence rate to zero increases as n increases

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, proof-explanation

> I am trying to prove that in the equation: $$F_{i,n} =
>  \prod_{0}^{n-1}_{−(+1)}_{−}$$ as $i > n$, $i > 1$, $n \ge 1$, $n \longrightarrow
>  \infty$ and $_{−} \longrightarrow 0$, $$F \longrightarrow 0$$ as
>    well.

In the aformentioned equation, P is a real number (actually probability of something), raning from 0 to 1.

Any idea how I might be able to prove the theory in mathematics apart from proving it based on empirical results?

P.S. I am a Research Scientist with Computer Science background, lacking knowledge in theoretical mathematics. So any help related to this topic would help. Thank you in advance. With Regards, http://somdipdey.co.uk/

Comment: What is $P_{i-n}$?

Comment: Probability, ranging from 0 to 1. I will update this in the question as well. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Okay, but is $-$ the actual substraction sign? Is $F$ a function of $i$ and $n$? If so, what are you taking the product of?

Comment: Yes, $F$ is a function. The product is of two probabilities, $P_i$ and $P_{i-1}$ and the product continues for $n$ numbers.

Comment: So you mean $F_{i,n}=P_{i-n+1}P_{i-n+2} \ldots P_{i-1}P_i$?

Comment: @Mindlack Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Then the correct writing for $F_{i,n}$ is $\prod_{k=i-n+1}^i{P_k}$. Anyway, you then have $F_{i,n} \leq 1 \cdot P_i \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: @Mindlack Yes, that is correct. Apologies for my lack in theoretical mathematics. Is it possible to prove mathematically that if $P_i \longrightarrow 0$ then $F_{i,n} \longrightarrow 0$ is true as well? Thank you in advance.

Comment: That is exactly what I wrote, I think.

Comment: @Mindlack really appreciate your help in this. Thank you. But I was hoping is there anyway of break the problem step by step and then reach to the conclusion: $F_{i,n} \longrightarrow 0$ as $P_i→0$? I am aware that $F_{i,n} \le 1$ but what I want to prove mathematically (not using words) that as $P_i$ becomes smaller and smaller, close to 0, $F$ also converges to zero and not just les than or equal to one. Thanks a ton for your help.

Comment: I am sorry if I have been unclear: I did not merely write that $F_{i,n} \leq 1$. I wrote that $0 \leq F_{i,n} \leq P_i$.